# sender doesn't have enough funds to send tx

Tags: blockchain, uniswap, ethereum-wallet-dapp, uniswapv3

i am trying to create a uniswap pool but when i am testing my smart contract i am getting an error .

```
import { expect } from "chai";
import { ethers, network } from "hardhat";

const DAI = "0x6B175474E89094C44Da98b954EedeAC495271d0F";
const USDC = "0xA0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48";
const DAI_WHALE = "0xbEbc44782C7dB0a1A60Cb6fe97d0b483032FF1C7";
const USDC_WHALE = "0xbEbc44782C7dB0a1A60Cb6fe97d0b483032FF1C7";

describe("LiquidityExamples", () => {
  let liquidityExamples;
  let accounts;
  let dai;
  let usdc;

  before(async () => {
    accounts = await ethers.getSigners();
    const LiquidityExamples = await ethers.getContractFactory(
      "LiquidityExamples"
    );
    liquidityExamples = await LiquidityExamples.deploy();
    await liquidityExamples.waitForDeployment();

    dai = await ethers.getContractAt("IERC20", DAI);
    usdc = await ethers.getContractAt("IERC20", USDC);

    await network.provider.request({
      method: "hardhat_impersonateAccount",
      params: [DAI_WHALE],
    });

    const daiWhale = await ethers.getSigner(DAI_WHALE);

    await network.provider.request({
      method: "hardhat_impersonateAccount",
      params: [USDC_WHALE],
    });

    const usdcWhale = await ethers.getSigner(USDC_WHALE);

    const daiAmount = BigInt("100");
    const usdcAmount = BigInt("1000000");

    console.log(
      "USDC Whale balance before transfer: ",
      (await usdc.balanceOf(usdcWhale.address)).toString()
    );
    console.log("USDC Amount to transfer: ", usdcAmount.toString());

    console.log("DAI Balance : ",(await dai.balanceOf(accounts[0].address)));
    console.log("USDC Balance : ",(await usdc.balanceOf(accounts[0].address)));

    expect(await dai.balanceOf(daiWhale.address)).to.gte(daiAmount);
    expect(await usdc.balanceOf(usdcWhale.address)).to.gte(usdcAmount);
    const balance = await ethers.provider.getBalance(accounts[0]);
    console.log("Ether Balance :",balance);
    console.log("Pass 1");
    await dai.connect(daiWhale).transfer(accounts[0].address, daiAmount);
    console.log("Pass 2");
    await usdc.connect(usdcWhale).transfer(accounts[0].address, usdcAmount);
    console.log("pass 3");
  });
});
```

the error is :

[image]

The error is occurring with code  **await dai.connect(daiWhale).transfer(accounts[0].address, daiAmount);**
if anyone knows why this error is happening , **please help**